# Хранение хеша паролей, hash_pbkdf2, С++

Tags: php, c++, md5, хеширование

Есть БД с пользователями и их паролями, последние хранятся в виде хешей hash_pbkdf2("md5", ...); Нужно работать с БД их C++ и, соответственно, нужна функция, аналогичная hash_pbkdf2(); для проверки существующих при авторизации и добавления новых.

1. Есть ли исходные коды hash_pbkdf2() под с++ или описание алгоритма?
2. Подскажите другие хорошие алгоритмы получения хеша пароля. Возможно будет проще взять другой алгоритм, к примеру тот же md5($salt.$pass.$salt), хотя, насколько я понимаю, он уже не является надежным.

Требуется сделать быстро, хорошо и чтобы в php был тот же алгоритм.

Comment: mikelsv : Дня два назад был похожий вопрос по PHP. Помимо ответов на него, ознакомьтесь с [моим комментарием](http://goo.gl/DvN2wJ). Я привёл в нём fallback для PHP < 5.5 - как раз таки всё сделано "ручками". Из комментария вы могли заметить, что у yii 2 существует целый класс [Security](https://goo.gl/xHP5j3), где, уверен, вы найдёте много полезного.

Comment: А так - [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php) (возвращает уже подсоленный пароль в виде хэша) и [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-verify.php) (проверяет его на валидность, который, к примеру, пришёл из БД).

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идет о hash_pbkdf2() из PHP, исходники этой функции есть в самом PHP, файл ext\hash\hash.c